# setState proplem with using ckeditor in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I want to have an update page in order to edit the inserted company information. I don't know why when I use the onChange property of the ckEditor, it makes the other company information fields except about, empty.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

import { COMMENT, GREEN, PURPLE } from "../../helpers/colors";
import { companySchema } from '../../validations/companyValidation';
import { getMyCompany} from '../../services/employerService';

const CompanyEdit = () => {
    const [companyInfo, setCompanyInfo] = useState({
    });

    const setFormCompanyInfo = (event) => {
        setCompanyInfo({ ...companyInfo, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const { data, status } = await getMyCompany();
                setCompanyInfo(data.myCompany);
            } catch (error) {

            }

        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const submitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(companyInfo);
        try {
            await companySchema.validate(companyInfo, { abortEarly: false });
            //todo ....

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.inner);
        }

    }

    return (
        <>
            <section className="p-3">

                <div className="container">

                    <hr style={{ backgroundColor: GREEN }} />
                    <div className="row mt-5">
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <form onSubmit={(e) => submitForm(e)}>
                               
                                <div className="mb-2">
                                    <input
                                        value={companyInfo.name}
                                        onChange={setFormCompanyInfo}
                                        name="name"
                                        type="text"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        placeholder={'Company Name'}
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div className="mb-2">
                                    <input

                                        value={companyInfo.personnels}
                                        onInput={setFormCompanyInfo}
                                        name="personnels"
                                        type="number"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        placeholder={'Number of Employees'}
                                    />
                                </div>

                                <div className="mb-2">
                                    <CKEditor
                                        editor={ClassicEditor}
                                       
                                        data={companyInfo.about}
                                        onChange={(event, editor) => {
                                            setCompanyInfo({ ...companyInfo, "about": editor.getData() })
                                        }}
                                         
                                    />

                                </div>

                                <div className="mx-2">
                                    {
                                        <button
                                            type="submit"
                                            className="btn"
                                            style={{ backgroundColor: PURPLE }}>
                                            {'register company'}
                                        </button>
                                    }

                                    <Link
                                        to={"/employer/jobs"}
                                        className="btn mx-2"
                                        style={{ backgroundColor: COMMENT }}
                                    >
                                        {'cancel'}
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section >
        </>
    );
}

export default CompanyEdit;
```

What can I do to solve my problem? Maybe I use the ckEditor in the wrong way or I have some problems in understanding the react basics.